# Correct way to write "to the power" with an indexed parameter

Tags: article-writing

Quick (and simple) question: I'm writing a formula that uses parameters with a subscript, and they are squared. What is the correct way to typeset that? See below.

I fear that in (1) the $^2$ might be seen as an additional characteristic and not as "squared".

1. $s_1^2$
2. ${s_1}^2$
3. $({s_1})^2$

Comment: Personally, I don’t think there’s wrong in writing 1.

Comment: According to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, questions about typesetting equations  are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I think option (3) makes it clear that you want to square $s_1$. Otherwise, maybe just write $s_1 \cdot s_1$.